# Ruby regex replace all but what's within parenthesis

Tags: ruby, regex

How do I replace all but what's within parenthesis

For instance:

```
some_html=some_html.gsub(/&lt;a href=\"([^\"]+)\"/,  "");
```

now I would like to replace that string with: whatever is in the parenthesis.

Comment: I'm puzzled..Please correct me if I'm wrong, you want to replace all characters inside the paranthesis?..or you just wanna remove them. And also is like this `some_html = <a href="(blah blah 123)"` ???

Comment: the title of this question is now improved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand your question, so if it needed feel free to correct me.

I assume you need to transform following `<a href="needless[target]trash"` into something like `<a href="target"`

So following code do the job:

```
some_html.gsub!(/(<a href=")[^"]*\[([^"]+)\][^"]*"/, '\\1\\2"')
```